# procedure declaration error (PLS-00488)

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to make a procedure return a subset of records as a single type `a_ntt` meeting a certain requirement for which I am trying to define a cursor `a_cur`, and this is the relevant code for my question:

```
a_t a_cur%ROWTYPE;

TYPE a_ntt IS TABLE OF a_t; 
l_a a_ntt;
```

My database server throws PLS-00488 (invalid variable declaration object must be a type or subtype) considering variable `a_t`. I would like to know why. To me it seems I have provided a type to `a_t`, I would suggest  `ROWTYPE` does that for me, but obviously I am not getting something.

I would like to know why this error occurs, why declaring `a_t` as `a_cur%ROWTYPE` does not prevent this.

Just to make sure, I have resolved the issue by adding `%TYPE` to the line, so `TYPE a_ntt IS TABLE OF a_t%TYPE;`, but I would like to know why this is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a_t` is not a type. It is a variable whose type is `a_cur%ROWTYPE`. You can't use it as a type.

`a_t%TYPE` is a type though, so that works.

The syntax diagrams for the "collection variable declaration" is [in the PL/SQL docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/collection_variable.htm#LNPLS01307). You'll see that either you need a type, or a [`rowtype_attribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/rowtype_attribute.htm#LNPLS01342) which has cursor, table or view name with `%ROWTYPE` attached, or a [`type_attribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/type_attribute.htm#LNPLS01352) which is essentially a variable name with `%TYPE` attached.